# C# code behind Required validation

Tags: c#, validation, requiredfieldvalidator

I am writing a c# code for a  Required field validator for a Multiline text box.

I have a issue in the run time:

> when i won't enter any text inside the
>   text box

1. For first Click on submit (Button) it shows the error message
2. For second Click on submit it won't validate the text box and the form is submitted.

> Same two issues when i even enter any
>   text inside the text box.

Overall it is not validating...

Please help me on what could be the possible bug in the below code.

```
    txtReport = new InputFormTextBox();
    txtReport.TextMode = TextBoxMode.MultiLine;
    txtReport.RichText = true;
    txtReport.RichTextMode = SPRichTextMode.Compatible;
    txtReport.Rows = 5;
    txtReport.Width = new Unit(200);
    txtReport.ID = "txtReport";
    txtReport.Text.Trim();
    this.Controls.Add(txtReport);


    reqVal = new RequiredFieldValidator();
    reqVal.ID = "reqVal";
    reqVal.ControlToValidate = txtReport.ID;

    reqVal.SetFocusOnError = true;
    reqVal.ErrorMessage = "*Comments field is mandatory";
    reqVal.Enabled = true;
    this.Controls.Add(reqVal);
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you have `.CausesValidation` property set to `true`?

Comment: @KMan that i have given in the button properties button.CausesValidation = true;

Answer (score 1):

From what it sounds like you are not re-adding the validator after the first submit, causing the second submit not to validate. But it's hard to tell from the fragment you posted (in what event/method is this being called?).

Comment: in the button event it is called "button.CausesValidation=true;"